# Does the Bochner-Kodaira-Nakano inequality hold w.r.t. some singular metric?

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

The following contents are copied from Demailly's e-book  Chapter VII-(2.7)-*Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry.*

Let $(X, \omega)$ be a compact hermitian manifold, $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{C}} X=n,$ and **$E$ a hermitian** holomorphic vector bundle over $X$. For any section $u \in \mathscr{C}_{p, q}^{\infty}(X, E)$ we have $\left\langle\left\langle\Delta^{\prime \prime} u, u\right\rangle\right\rangle=$ $\left\|D^{\prime \prime} u\right\|^{2}+\left\|\delta^{\prime \prime} u\right\|^{2}$ and the similar formula for $\Delta_{\tau}^{\prime}$ gives $\left\langle\left\langle\Delta_{\tau}^{\prime} u, u\right\rangle\right\rangle \geqslant 0 .$ Theorem 1.4
implies therefore
(2.1)
$$
\left\|D^{\prime \prime} u\right\|^{2}+\left\|\delta^{\prime \prime} u\right\|^{2} \geqslant \int_{X}\left(\langle[\mathrm{i} \Theta(E), \Lambda] u, u\rangle+\left\langle T_{\omega} u, u\right\rangle\right) d V
$$
This inequality is known as **the Bochner-Kodaira-Nakano inequality**.

Of course, the above follows from the **Bochner-Kodaira-Nakano identity** (Demailly's e-book  Chapter VII-(1.2)) whose proof depends on a trick of taking the Taylor  expansion of corresponding operators. The existence of the Taylor  expansion tell us that the smooth metric of the above  bundle $E$ is adopted.

**My question is:** can we still get the same Bochner-Kodaira-Nakano identity or Bochner-Kodaira-Nakano inequality when the vector bundle  **$E$ is equipped with a singular metric**.